# Kyocera printer page count SNMP

Tags: printer, snmp

trouble finding out Kyocera printer page count...

Standard Print MIB says:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.10.2.1.4.1.1 = Counter32: 486492
```

The web interface gives 433726
which is the same as

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1347.43.10.1.1.12.1.1 = INTEGER: 433726
```

Looking at MIB Depot only goes up to value SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1347.43.10.1.1.7....

What the h*** is going on? ;-)

Which one of the values is correct?

Where can I obtain the MIB for this printer (FS-3920DN)? (current MIB for enterprise 1347 = Kyocera)

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.toggle.com/lv/group/view/kl199932/Kyocera_Ai2310_3010_RC-2310_3010_SNMP_Print_Utility__MIB_File.htm

Comment: I already found all that (contains MIB for some enterprises 901 stuff) so it's not for me. I said I need Kyocera (enterprise 1347) MIB. The printer BTW is a FS3920DN

Comment: Ah sorry. You know, it is often useful to mention in your question things you've already tried. Some details of the printer (model#) are useful too.